# Is there a way to read mp3 file from physical phone(external and internal storage). I have tried it but i am not getting it

Tags: java, android

I am not getting any mp3 file back from getPlayList

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> songList = getPlayList(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        String [] fileNameList = new String[songList.size()];
        String [] artistList = new String[songList.size()];
    enter code here
        if(songList!=null){
            for(int i = 0 ; i < songList.size() ; i++){

                fileNameList[i] = songList.get(i).get("file_song");
                artistList[i] = songList.get(i).get("file_artist");
                //here you will get list of file name and file path that present in your device
                Log.e("file det ails "," name ="+fileNameList[i] +" path = "+artistList[i]);
            }
        }
        RecyclerView playListRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.playListRecyclerView);
        playListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        PlayListAdapter playListAdapter = new PlayListAdapter(fileNameList, artistList);
        playListRecyclerView.setAdapter(playListAdapter);
    }

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getPlayList(String rootPath) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            File rootFolder = new File(rootPath);
            File[] files = rootFolder.listFiles(); //here you will get NPE if directory doesn't contains  any file,handle it like this.
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    if (getPlayList(file.getAbsolutePath()) != null) {
                        fileList.addAll(getPlayList(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<>();
                    song.put("file_song", file.getName());
                    song.put("file_artist", file.getAbsolutePath());
                    fileList.add(song);
                }
            }
            return fileList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and i am getting an error of

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: `getPlayList()` can return null. And `null.size()` will throw your exception.

Comment: @blackapps i am new to android and i think that getPlayList() return null because it is not giving back any mp3 file.  So i want to know whether my code is wrong for getting back mp3 file from internal storage.

Comment: Your code is wrong indeed as you do not check for null and just continue as if you had a valid array list. Repair that first.

Comment: `//here you will get NPE ` No. Only at the next statement.